# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (20,2) (20,)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bayesian

I am building a Bayesian Ridge Regression using sklearn on the [Parkinson's Telemonitoring Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Parkinsons+Telemonitoring). This is the code:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn import linear_model


data1 = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
msk = np.random.rand(len(data1)) < 0.66
train =  data1[msk]
test = data1[~msk]
y = train[['motor_UPDRS','total_UPDRS']]
X = train.drop('motor_UPDRS',axis = 1)
X = X.drop('total_UPDRS',axis = 1)
labels = test[['motor_UPDRS','total_UPDRS']]
test = test.drop('motor_UPDRS',axis = 1)
test = test.drop('total_UPDRS',axis = 1)
clf = linear_model.BayesianRidge()
clf.fit(X,y)
```

The data set is divided into 66% training set and 33% test set ratio. When I run it,I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-c4e92f3e0bf9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Keshav/Desktop/Spring/ML/Project/parkinsons/main6.py', wdir='C:/Users/Keshav/Desktop/Spring/ML/Project/parkinsons')

  File "C:\Users\Keshav\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Keshav/Desktop/Spring/ML/Project/parkinsons/main6.py", line 27, in <module>
    clf.fit(X,y)

  File "C:\Users\Keshav\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\bayes.py", line 212, in fit
    self._set_intercept(X_mean, y_mean, X_std)

  File "C:\Users\Keshav\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 159, in _set_intercept
    self.coef_ = self.coef_ / X_std

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (20,2) (20,)
```

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Try adding an axis such that the shape of the second array is (20,1)... You can use `reshape` or just index it ie. `y = y[:, np.newaxis]`

Comment: Thanks @Alex!
Should I just add the line y = y[:, np.newaxis] before fitting? If so, I get TypeError: unhashable type as the error.
Can you please explain?
I don't understand the concept of shaping here..!

Comment: What is X.shape and y.shape? Oh and it seems you are feeding pandas dataframes? the ``values`` array of the pandas dataframe. Also: Do you intentionally fit two different targets? do you want to predict both?